# Raspberry Pi Boot USB Flash Drive Automatic Image Backup

Tags: usb, image, backup

I boot Raspberry Pi’s from USB Flash Drives and have been trying to utilize the **bkup_rpimage** found on [GitHub](https://github.com/lzkelley/bkup_rpimage).  I changed the drive to point to the USB Flash Drive in the *bkup_rpimage.sh* file; however, please note that the comments referring to the SD card were not changed in this file.  I have used the exact model and size of the boot USB Flash Drive and, also, used the same model USB Flash Drive that doubles the size of the boot USB Flash Drive.   The same errors (below) were generated for both USB Flash Drives when the backup script was run.  Is a larger USB Flash Drive required?  Any help with solving this will be appreciated.

Errors generated with `sudo sh bkup_rpimage.sh start -c /media/pi/BACKUPDRIVE/rpi_backup.img`

```
trap: SIGINT: bad trap
-e Starting SD Image backup process
-e Attaching /media/pi/BACKUPDRIVE/rpi_backup.img to /dev/loop0
losetup: /media/pi/BACKUPDRIVE/rpi_backup.img: Warning: file is smaller than 512 bytes; the loop device may be useless or invisible for system tools.
partx: /dev/loop0: failed to read partition table
-e Mounting /dev/loop0p1 and /dev/loop0p2 to /mnt/rpi_backup.img/
mount: special device /dev/loop0p2 does not exist
mount: special device /dev/loop0p1 does not exist
-e Skipping rsync since /mnt/rpi_backup.img/ is not a mount point
-e Flushing to disk
-e Unmounting /dev/loop0p1 and /dev/loop0p2 from /mnt/rpi_backup.img/
umount: /mnt/rpi_backup.img//boot: not mounted
umount: /mnt/rpi_backup.img/: not mounted
rmdir: failed to remove '/mnt/rpi_backup.img/': Directory not empty
-e Detaching /media/pi/BACKUPDRIVE/rpi_backup.img from /dev/loop0
partx: specified range <1:0> does not make sense
-e SD Image backup process completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying the error verbatim, you are not providing the correct location to save the image file. /media/pi/BACKUPDRIVE/rpi_backup.img will need to be changed to an existing directory where you want the file created